# Slow and Outlook Add In Disables

Tags: harmon.ie

Harmon IE is a great product. However some user are experiencing slower workings in Outlook, longer to load, and as such disable the addin or remove it all together.
Is there a way how this can be 'measured/tuned', get certainty it is the Harmon IE addin and not something else?
Thanks,
Gunther

Answer (score 0):

Please download --our latest 6.0.1 version-- from our web site and make sure to test it after disabling all the other addins to rule out any conflict.

---- Jean